# Get current item in LazyVstack inside scrollview when scroll ends

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-scrollview, lazyvstack

I want to print the currently displayed item in LazyVStack which is inside scrollview with paging enabled.

i have tried printing in onAppear of VerseView
The issues with printing inside onAppear are-

- onAppear gets called twice or more sometimes.
- onAppear doesnt get triggered when i just begin to scroll and cancels the scroll.

I SIMPLY WANT TO PRINT THE CURRENT ITEM WHICH IS DISPLAYED IN SCREEN WHENEVER I RELEASES THE SCROLL.

CODE IS :

```
    struct SwippableView: View {
    var data: [VerseModel]
  
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(data, id: \.id) { verse in
                   
                    VerseView(verse: verse)
                        .padding(0)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    
                }
            }.scrollTargetLayout()
                
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
        .scrollIndicators(.never)
        
    }
}
```

Additional info: Each view inside LazyVStack fills the entire screen

Comment: try using `.scrollPosition(id....)`, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/scrollposition(id:anchor:)

Comment: I know about scrollposition already,but dont know how to bind the current verse item in the code i provided.
Could you write the code and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach using `.scrollPosition` and a `.onChange` to print
the current verse that is on the screen when scrolling.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // --- for testing
    let verses = [VerseModel(id: 1, verse: "verse-1"), VerseModel(id: 2, verse: "verse-2"), VerseModel(id: 3, verse: "verse-3")]
    var body: some View {
        SwippableView(data: verses)
    }
}

// --- for testing
struct VerseModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    var verse: String
}

struct SwippableView: View {
    var data: [VerseModel]
    @State var scrolledID: Int?  // <--- here

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(scrolledID ?? 1)")  // <--- for testing
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(data, id: \.id) { verse in
                    VerseView(verse: verse)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
            }.scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
        .scrollIndicators(.never)
        .scrollPosition(id: $scrolledID) // <--- here
        .onChange(of: scrolledID) {
            print("----> scrolledID: \(scrolledID)")  // <--- here
        }
    }
}

// --- for testing
struct VerseView: View {
    var verse: VerseModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle().fill(Color.red.opacity(0.3))
            Text(verse.verse)
        }.frame(width: 333, height: 666)
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked..thanks a lot..if you dont mind, can you help me with my latest question too?